# NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_thread.title

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I recently learned Django and want to do some project and I thought let it be a forum website, but while making a discussion forum, when I log in and post data I get this error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_thread.title

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime 

class Thread(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('category', related_name="Thread", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Thread, Category

def addThread(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        thread_title = request.POST.get('threadtitle')
        thread_slug = request.POST.get('threadslug')    
        thread_category = request.POST.get('threadcategory')    
        thread_description = request.POST.get('threaddescription') 
        user = request.user  
        thread = Thread(title = thread_title, slug = thread_slug, category=thread_category, 
        description = thread_description, user = user) 
        thread.save() 
        messages.success(request, 'thread added successfully')
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the function like
def **str**(self):
return self.title

----------- remove above and add this

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        return self.title
    return 'Untitled
```

Comment: thank you for your comment...error was in html form templates in name attribute , the value i given in name was different from where i get from post request in views.py..i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Thread` model the title can't be null in the database. So, make sure that the HTML input is required and `request.POST.get('threadtitle')` exists and has a value.